# Android ToggleButton with Nine Patch stop working

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-theme

this is the situation:

myTheme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToggleButton" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_list</item>
        <item name="android:textOn">""</item>
        <item name="android:textOff">""</item>
        <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

toggle_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_selector" />
</layer-list>
```

toggle_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on"/>
</selector>
```

on onCheckedChanged I've inserted output to see what it does.
here the problem if i comment out the line

```
<item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleButton</item>
```

I see the standard button and my listener is called correctly,
with that line I see my buttons correcly,
but the listener is no longer called,
and the image does not change when i press the ToggleButton.
Someone could help me?
Thanks.